# В IE не воспроизводятся видео в плагине FOTORAMA

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Использую FOTORAMA и html5 video, http://fotorama.io/customize/html/.

Во всех браузерах видео воспроизводится корректно, а в IE нет. 
Cам слайдер работает корректно, есть табы и стрелки, все листается.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге для этой цели решил использовать старый добрый слайдер Swiper? Немного его закостомил, дописал парку строк js для остановки видео при листании и все. Видео-галерея готова. :)